# delay in an java applet program without using threads

Tags: java, applet, delay

Is it possible in java to make the program to sleep or wait for a particular time peroid ?

As in C++ we do `delay(1000);`.
I am writing a java applet **which does not include threads**, but I want it to delay the execution of some statements. Its a clock(Digital) applet. so I need to make part of my applet code to delay for 1 second.

Comment: There is no such thing as a Java applet or a Java application that "does not include threads."  There is always at least _one_ thread that runs your code, plus other threads that may be created by any libraries that you use, plus threads that exist to support the JVM itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. Do a little research into the `Thread.sleep()` method as well as Timers as well as...

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do that. sleeping for a second in the Event Dispatching Thread will prevent **any** event processing during that time. One second may not be that much, but in general this is not a good practice.

What you want to do is setup a timer with a 1s period.